# why there could be int placeholder in table name when using mysql?

Tags: mysql

this week i meet an strange case when using mysql.
The mysql server version is mysql 5.7.22,
the jdbc driver version is 8.0.23.
As i know, there could be no placeholders in table name.
But the following code could be executed normally.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(1) from g_?");
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

But if you use ps.setString(1, "1");
there will be mysql server error.
The table is created with
`create table g_1(t int not null)`.
I could not find any reference in mysql document.
Very appreciated for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with mysql, the substitution seems to be done on the client side in this case.

Comment: @Shadow It seems you are right. The prepare and bind executed in client side, and it seems not the same behavior preparedstatment in oracle. By the way, i debug the mysql connector java source code for just a while, need further confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion:
The prepare and binding of sql statement are all done by mysql client, 
different from many rdbms such as oracle, as the prepare stage is processed at server side,
in order for soft parse to speed performance.
So this kind of code maybe just suit for mysql.